# Making universal build for iphone application with xcode 4.51

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, xib, universal

I had an old project which uses XIB for each UIViewControler.That was intended for I Phone but now I want to make that project with universal build that is for Iphone as wall as IPad also.The problem is that when I changed the build type to Universal and used coding like

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
 // ipad coordinates
    }
else
{
 //iphone coordinates
}
```

this the display is correct on iphone and ipad but on ipad the buttons are not taking click event on entire button but only on a small portion of button.Though I am not loading Nib but it is taking crated iphone xib file internally  and I think thats why it's button behavior is not in accordance to ipad view. I am confused that what I should do?How to make copy of XIB for Ipad and load them depending upon device.It is to mention here that I am not loading             any nib from my code but It is being called internally. Please help

Answer (score 0):

For `universal` app you can make 2 xib
**1 - >  yourView_iPhone

2 - >  yourView_iPad**

And load each `xib` according yo your `idiom`

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    yourView  *obj = [[yourView alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourView_iPad " bundle:nil];

    // ipad coordinates
}
else
{
    yourView  *obj = [[yourView alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourView_iPhone " bundle:nil];

    //iphone coordinates
}
```

Comment: Actully I knew this but the problem is that old code don't load any nib from code but it uses initWithNibNmae:nil and there is asscociated iphone xib. I hope only- if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    yourView  *obj = [[yourView alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourView_iPad " bundle:nil];

    // ipad coordinates
} will work  and  in else part the old code will work as previously.Let me try this.Thanks for reply.